# Avoid large images with NSPasteboard

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit, nspasteboard

I'm working on an application that utilizes NSPasteboard as the medium to allow users to grab image files from other applications.

Occasionally a user will want to copy a very large image, which can lead to stalling the main thread pretty badly, as the pasteboard chokes on a 30MB file.

Is there a way to set a limit on pasteboard data size (and get an error when exceeded) or a way to get the data size without touching the data? We can't request the data size from the pasteboard because to do so the pasteboard would already need to contain the large image data (which would be too late).

Thanks!

Comment: It is a tough one. Theories (and not even answers) are also appreciated.

Comment: The obvious solution would be to transfer URLs for image files instead of image data. Can you explain why you didn't/can't do that?

Comment: This is intra-app on OS X and the images are stored inside the *from* application, say Photoshop. So no URLs available. What I'm looking for is a way to get metrics about the promised pasteboard object without having to actually touch the object.